# Responding with "OK" & "Welcome" to "Thank you"

Tags: politeness, colloquialisms, speech

Please, let me make it clear that my question is not asking how native speakers usually respond to "Thank you". Before posting this question I did some research and I also read this discussion: [How do native English speakers respond to "Thank you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-do-native-english-speakers-respond-to-thank-you)  In my opinion none of the suggested answers apply to my question.

This is a specific question on the appropriateness of two specific responses.

Let's take a situation when I ask my colleague to briefly explain me something. And after he has done it, I say, "Thank you".

1. Is it polite to respond with an "OK" to my "Thank you"? (That's how a native English speaker replied to me today.)
2. Is it acceptable in an informal situation to respond with "You welcome" (without "are") or even with "Welcome"? Responding, "You are welcome" sometimes feels too long to me :)

UPDATE. Today two different people responded with "OK"  to my "Thank you" and "Thanks", so it seems it's not that rare.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: *[How do native English speakers respond to “Thank you”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516)*; *[When should “no problem” replace “you're welcome” as a response to “thank you”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671)*; *[What happened to “You're welcome?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212215)*; and *[Can “Sure thing” mean “You're welcome”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30554)* among others.

Comment: @choster: I am not asking a general question on how to reply to "Thank you". I am not asking about replacing "You're welcome" with "No problem". I am not asking about "Sure thing". I did read the discussions referenced by the links you posted and have found no answer to my questions there.

Comment: @nightcoder The linked questions indicate how English speakers customarily respond to *thank you*; neither *okay* nor *welcome* nor certainly *you welcome* make any appearance. I do hear *okay* and *welcome* from various non-native speakers, but a fluent speaker would say *it's okay* or *you're welcome* (though in rapid speech, sounds may be swallowed; *'sokay* or *y'welkm* ). As for politeness, none of those words or phrases is vulgar, so whether or not they are polite in an informal setting is a matter of delivery: tone, body language, and other context.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shorten "You are welcome", use "You're welcome". "You welcome" isn't grammatically correct. You could also use "No problem" instead.

"You're welcome" or "no problem" is what I would use after someone had thanked me for explaining something to them. Responding with "OK" sounds a little odd to me, though I don't think it's impolite.

Comment: Thank you. What about responding with "Welcome"? Is it acceptable in informal situations?

Comment: I think "Welcome" is a little too brief - it sounds a bit abrupt and could be construed as sarcastic.

Comment: If I were to choose the lesser of two evils, what would be better, replying with "Ok" or with "Welcome" (let's take the situation in question)? (sorry for so many questions from me)

Answer (score 2):

1) I wouldn't use "Ok" as an answer to "Thank you". It's not something you would say. It's not rude like swearing, but it would seem distracted, as if the person didn't actually hear what you were saying.

2) You can say "You're welcome". Younger people might also respond, "No problem!" or "Sure!"

Comment: Thank you. What about responding with "Welcome"? Is it acceptable in informal situations?

Comment: @nightcoder - Yes, you could use just "Welcome" informally. But it could come off as curt or terse or even childish depending on the tone you deliver it in.

Comment: ah!! the troubles we get into in this life

Answer (score 2):

Rarely, native english speakers do respond to "thank you" with "ok".  When they do it's likely they're indicating that the "thank you" was inappropreate.

If I slap your face and your responce is "thank you", my reply of "ok" may mean I think you're an idiot for thanking me for slapping you.  Particularly if I'm rolling my eyes at the time.

Ok is very expressive.  Litteraly it means "all correct".  In typical usage though, what it means depends a lot on the tone used when it's said.

Comment: Why would *anyone* respond with a "thank you" after being slapped in the face? The OP's question describes a perfectly normal, typical situation. You do me a courtesy, I express my gratitude. You reply with: *That's OK.*, now do some people omit the *that*, I can't say,  but it's plausible.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm using it as an example precisely because it makes the "thank you" an inappropriate response. Responding to an appropriate "thank you" with "ok"  is not typical and (without knowing the tone used) can easily be taken as being itself inappropriate.  The most typical sincere response to "thank you" is another "thank you".   I'd put any of these other answers ahead of "ok" as a likely response to an appropriate, "thank you".

Answer (score 2):

> Is it polite to respond with an "OK" to my "Thank you"? (That's how a
>   native English speaker replied to me today.)

Well, *I* wouldn't respond that way, but there are people who do.  Don't take offense.

> Is it acceptable in an informal situation to respond with "You
>   welcome" (without "are") or even with "Welcome"? Responding, "You are
>   welcome" sometimes feels too long to me :)

I can't imagine a native speaker saying "You welcome."  Perhaps you misheard?

"Welcome", in a casual situation, is okay, especially if the speaker is not much of a talker, or needs to move on quickly, for example, to the next customer.

---

I hope I may now be forgiven if I relate something short and funny.  When I ask my twelve-year-old to do something he finds onerous, such as put the dishes away, and I thank him when he's done, he likes to say, "A problem!!"

Answer (score 1):

I respond with "anytime" or "happy to" sometimes. I use "you are welcome" and "no problem" mostly.